# CakePHP view not rendering

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a basic application being baked by CakePHP.

Now i want to add a new action'listjobs' in my model controller class and a corresponding 'listjobs' view in the /Template/Job/listjobs.ctp.

From my model's index view i added one more action in the side navigation bar.
like this

```
<li><?= $this->Html->link(__('View Jobs'),['action' => 'listjobs']) ?></li>
```

When i click on the link 'View Jobs' control is directed to the action method of my model's controller but its not taking the list jobs 's view.

Code for my action method

```
public function listjobs()
    {
        $this->log("inside list jobs",'debug');
        $this->render('listjobs');
    }
```

The listjobs.ctp contains a very basic code as following

```
<div class="actions columns large-2 medium-3">
     <h3><?= __('Actions') ?></h3>
    <ul class="side-nav">
        <li>< Git Hub >

        </li>
        <li>< Stack overflow >

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Not able to find out why the view is not rendered rather the index view is getting rendered.

Links loaded according to chrome console in order

(1) http://localhost/myjobs/job/listjobs

(2) http://localhost/myjobs/job

So (1) should have been loaded with the view..it should not been redirected to (2)

Regards,
Saurav

Comment: It's not going to your link ? or not generating any data ? Please add more information.

Comment: and consider posting your controller listjobs() method code

Comment: thanks Arilia and Alimon... its not going to my link and i have edited the post with the code for listjobs()

Comment: so: what link does it generates? Where does it go?

Comment: so this is what i can see in my chrome console ..first it goes to http://localhost/myjobs/job/listjobs and then it goes to http://localhost/myjobs/job where job is my model name

Comment: did you check your routes ?

Comment: No, Job is the method name.

Comment: @Karan do i have to check my routes file ?...my application model is already baked

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use like this.

```
<li><?php echo $this->Html->link('View Jobs',array('controller' => 'MyModel', 'action' => 'listjobs')); ?></li>
```

Your view will be.

```
public function listjobs()
    {
        $this->log("inside list jobs",'debug');

    }
```

I think you don't need to render, your view will be render by default, you will need to send data like that `$this->set(compact('VarName'));`

Secondly `$this->log("inside list jobs",'debug');` if log is a method then you need to set action, then it will be.

```
$this->setAction('log');
```

Try, if you get error, then let me know. If your work proper then, you view will work.

http://localhost/myjobs/job/listjobs

this link defines.

http://localhost/SiteName/ControllerName/ActionName/Parameter

Get review and study this page.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html

Thanks

Comment: yes that so the controller name will be MyModelController

Comment: yes i tried the view code but it did not work...then i explicitly used this->render but still it did not work

Comment: thanks for the persistent help...log was just using the cakephp log apis

Comment: did that ...but it does not work...do i have to change the routes.php file if i add a new action ?

Comment: You have a very little issue, follow this small tutorial. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-small-web-application-with-cakephp-on-a-vps-part-1 , then may be you will solve you issue. : )

Answer (score 0):

ok...i did some debugging of the cakephp framework code.
I was using an auth component for my login functionality.

I found that the newly added action was not allowed to pass the through filter of auth component. so i added the newly added action in the beforefilter method of appcontroller like this. i guess the crud operations are already added in the filter by default.

```
$this->Auth->allow(['index', 'view', 'display','listjobs','add','delete']);
```

cheers,

Saurav